# how to properly inject middleware in NodeJS route

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

How can i inject my middleware function 'checkAuthenticated' into my get route below? 
not sure how to properly inject the code below.  Please let me know.  thank you very much.

```
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.header('authorization')) {
    return res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized request.  Missing authentication header'});
  }

  let token = req.header('authorization').split(' ')[1];

  let payload = jwt.decode(token, '123');

  if(!payload) {
    return res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized request.  Authetication header invalid'});
  }

  req.user = payload;

  next();
}

router.route('/:user_id')
  .get((req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(user);
      }
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options here.  I typically use:

```
router.use('*', checkAuthenticated);
```

Another option is:

```
router.get('/:user_id', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => { ... })
```

Or, using your example of `router.route...`:

```
router.route('/:user_id').get(checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => { ... })
```

You can also chain them together:

```
router.route('/:user_id').get(checkAuthenticated).get((req, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: awesome thanks, but what if i wanted to inject in specific routes and verbs? for instance. router.route('/:user_id') .post() .get() but not put() etc.

Comment: I've updated to reflect multiple ways of handling this.  #3 is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Your awesome man!  If i could upvote you, i would, but my rep is low.  thank you very much man!

Answer (score 0):

check this  hope it will help you

```
router.route('/:user_id')
.all((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
})
.get((req, res) => {
  res.json(req.user);
});
```